# Comparing two files and printing 2nd column if value of column 1 (file1) is less than to value of column 1 in file 2

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I got 2 files.

File 1:

```
abc 40
cde 50
efg 100
```

File 2:

```
cde 35
efg 100
abc 45
```

The output should be

```
cde "value is below normal"
```

If the value of column 2 of file 2 is less than the value of column 2 of file 1 it will print column 1 and the text `value is below normal`.

Im trying this with awk, but when I use the if condition for I got a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your `awk` code. Then we can help you to fix the syntax error or other problems in your code. Additionally you should define what should happen if the first value of a line from File 2 is not found in File 1, or state if this cannot happen in your use case.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == FNR {
    first[$1]=$2
}
NR != FNR {
    second[$1]=$2
}
END {
    for (i in second) {
        if (second[i] < first[i])
            print i, "\"value is below normal\""
    }
}
```

The first pattern (`NR == FNR`) is an AWK trick that matches only on the first file and its rule adds all encountered values to the `first` array. The second pattern is the same, except it matches only on the second (and 3rd, 4th, etc. but it doesn't matter here) file and adds values to the `second` array. After both files are processed the last rule goes through all remembered values, compares them and prints the result like you asked.